# GTX 1080 causes PC to freeze on motherboard splash

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, desktop-computer

I recently upgraded from GTX 690 to GTX 1080. My motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-X79S-UP5. Bios id and version are 8A10AG01 F1.

System boots fine with GTX 690, but with GTX 1080, the bios splash screen shows for a long time.

The beep code I get is initially what I hear when it posts correctly, followed by a long pause and then a shorter beep. This long pause-shorter beep cycles a few time before it just stops.

Processor is i7 3930k.

Any ideas what might be the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: PSU too weak.  BIOS level not up-to-date.  Incorrect installation.  Etc. etc.  Have you tried the 1080 in another computer to confirm it actually works yet?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. It's fairly clear that the PSU can handle the 1080 if it can take the 690. Either way, I solved it with a BIOS update like you said

Answer (score 1):

I have now got it working.

The issue was BIOS was outdated.

I had to go to the page for my motherboard on the Gigabyte website, go to 'Support and Downloads' and download the '@BIOS' from the utilities section, as well as the latest BIOS version from the BIOS section.

I ran the @BIOS program and updated from the file X79SUP5.F4.

After that, the PC rebooted, power cycled a couple of times and then worked correctly.